# child process hanging while reading from stdin (fork/dup2 race condition)?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork, dup2

I have a process that forks in order to execute a subprocess, which receive an entry from stdin and writes to stdout.

My code in short is as follows:

```
int fd[2];
int fd2[2];
if (pipe(fd) < 0 || pipe(fd2) < 0)
        throws exception;

pid_t p = fork();
if (p == 0) // child
{
        close(fd[0]); //not needed
        dup2( fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2( fd[1],STDERR_FILENO);
        close(fd2[1]); //not needed

        //what if  write calls on parent process execute first?
        //how to handle that situation
        dup2( fd2[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        string cmd="./childbin";

        if (execl(cmd.c_str(),(char *) NULL) == -1)
        {
                exit (-1);
        }
        exit(-1);
}
else if (p > 0) // parent
{
        close(fd[1]); //not needed
        close(fd2[0]);
        if (write(fd2[1],command.c_str(),command.size())<0)
        {
                throw exception;
        }

        close(fd2[1]);

        //waits for child to finish.
        //child process actually hangs on reading for ever from stdin.
        pidret=waitpid(p,&status,WNOHANG))==0)

.......

}
```

The child process remains waiting forever for data in STDIN. Is there maybe a race condition between the child and parent process? I think that could be the problem but not quite sure and also not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Some useful information.
The parent process is a daemon and this code runs several times per second. It works 97% of the times (~3% of the cases, the child process remains in the state described before).

**UPDATE 2**
After added validation in dup2 call, there is no error there, next condition is never raised.

```
if(dup2(...) == -1) {
     syslog(...)
}
```

Comment: What's the return value / errno on the 3% failure cases for dup2?

Comment: @Surt actually, I realized I'm not handling the return from dup2. I will update the code and test it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you need to to create a pipe for parent->child communications? Can't you just use STDOUT/STDIN as-is? Also how much is written on the pipe? If your children exceeds `PIPE_BUF` writes it will block waiting for the pipe to be emptied, but your parent is already blocked on `waitpid()` -- probably not the issue here but it can be a concern later.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a [wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) that is why you in 3% of the cases run the parent before the child. See the example at the bottom.

Also you should call `close` on the fd's you don't use before doing anything else.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "missing a wait"?

Comment: @ArturoGarcia see the link for explanation.

Comment: Which one? The only link in your answer goes to the man page of wait. I know what a wait is. Can you be more specific?

Comment: hmm it was clear to me yesterday that the order of execution of the threads might influence the outcome, but now I'm in doubt that wait is the right thing :(